# How to execute task that calls clean on subprojects without using aggregation?

Tags: sbt

I want make a take `cleanAll` that executes the `clean` task on a number of subprojects. I don't want to use aggregation just for the sake of `clean`.

We've run into issues with play's asset routes when we've been using submodules.

It's well documented how to create a new task, but how do I call a task on a subproject?

Comment: You call clean on root - and it calls clean on subprojects.

Comment: No it does not, only when you aggregate, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Run `cleanFiles` from root, or `find . -name target | xargs rm -Rf`

Comment: cleanFiles only lists the directories lib_managed and target, but doesn't really clean anything. I want to clean a specific set of subprojects, not all target directories we can find in some directory structure. Not safe, what if somebody has a target directory or file in their source control??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example by Jacek Laskowski I've come up with the following plugin that should be placed in your `/project` folder:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.AutoPlugin
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin

object CleanAllPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  val cleanAll = taskKey[Unit]("Cleans all projects in a build, regardless of dependencies")

  override def requires = JvmPlugin

  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    cleanAllTask
  )

  def cleanAllTask = cleanAll := Def.taskDyn {
    val allProjects = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)
    clean.all(allProjects)
  }.value
}
```

The plugin can now be added to the root project for usage:

```
val main = Project("root", file("."))
  .enablePlugins(CleanAllPlugin)
```

It can be executed in SBT by calling: `cleanAll`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `build.sbt`:

```
val selectDeps = ScopeFilter(inDependencies(ThisProject))

clean in Compile := clean.all(selectDeps).value
```

It assumes that the `build.sbt` file is in the project that has `clean` executed on itself and `dependsOn` projects.

If you need it in `project/Build.scala`, just add the following:

```
val selectDeps = ScopeFilter(inDependencies(ThisProject))
val cleanInSubprojects = Seq(
  clean in Compile := clean.all(selectDeps).value
)
```

and add `cleanInSubprojects` to settings of every project:

```
// definition of a project goes here
  .settings(cleanInSubprojects: _*)
```

Comment: How does this from a Build.scala file?

Comment: Can you gist.github.com the build definition (Scala+sbt) and share the link so I could review and help? I'd appreciate.